# Swift AWS Cognito Login throwing "Invalid Refresh Token" after working several times

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-cognito, refresh-token

I have been trying to solve this problem for an hour but haven't had any luck. Basically, I am using the AWS Cognito iOS SDK for my Swift app's login and after it automatically logging in the user smoothly a couple of times, it will suddenly throw an "Invalid Refresh Token." I used this Github example to program my own: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/tree/master/CognitoYourUserPools-Sample/Swift

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Can You show some code what you had try out first!

Answer (score 1):

Do you have user device tracking enabled? It seems that the token does not automatically refresh when this is turned on. If you have it enabled I recommend disabling it and then checking if the token refreshes automatically.

Comment: Do you know a way to have device tracking enabled and have the refresh token exchange to work?

Comment: Are you using Amplify or the AWS-SDK?

Comment: I'm using the aws sdk